# Как правильно запрашивать данные из БД для отображения на нескольких страницах?

Tags: node.js, nosql

У меня нет опыта веб-разработки, но сейчас я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде движка для блога на node.js+mongodb. В базе данных у меня есть куча текстовых сообщений; их надо выводить на определенной странице сайта. Проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как это лучше организовать. 
Допустим, сообщения я выдаю по ссылке типа `http://mysite.com/messages` . Сообщений в наличии может оказаться больше, чем надо показывать на одной странице, тогда на вторую страницу будут вести ссылки вида `http://mysite.com/messages?page=2`.

Вопросы:

1. Если я буду делать запрос к бд каждый раз, как пользователь запрашивает страницу, не создаст ли это слишком большую нагрузку на сервер? Можно (и нужно ли) этого избегать?
2. Для первой страницы можно делать запрос с ограничением, типа `db.things.find().limit(20)` ,но для пятой страницы в таком случае нужно будет нечто вроде `db.things.find().limit(5*20)` . При этом запрос вернет 100 записей, из которых нужны только 20. Это нормально?

Comment: Если юзаете mongodb - настоятельно рекомендую использовать mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если я буду делать запрос к бд каждый раз, как пользователь запрашивает страницу, не создаст ли это слишком большую нагрузку на сервер? Можно (и нужно ли) этого избегать?

Можно использовать кеширование. Страницы будут отрендерены в статические. Обновлять при добавлении нового сообщения. (Хотя это может быть бесполезным, если сообщения добавляются слишком часто).

> Для первой страницы можно делать запрос с ограничением, типа db.things.find().limit(20) ,но для пятой страницы в таком случае нужно будет нечто вроде db.things.find().limit(5*20) . При этом запрос вернет 100 записей, из которых нужны только 20. Это нормально?

Для этого есть [skip()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bskip%28%29%7D%7D), там же есть примечание:

> **Paging Costs**
>
> Unfortunately skip can be (very) costly and requires the server to walk from the beginning of the collection, or index, to get to the offset/skip position before it can start returning the page of data (limit). As the page number increases skip will become slower and more cpu intensive, and possibly IO bound, with larger collections.
>
> Range based paging provides better use of indexes but does not allow you to easily jump to a specific page.

Т.е. в официальной документации советуют использовать для этого обычные индексы.

Например можно завести индексированное поле number, которое будет расти по мере добавления, и использовать в запросах операции `$lt` и `limit()`, для выборки конкретного набора (от и до).

```
db.things.find({"number" : {"$lt" : (last_message_number - 20*n}}).limit(20)
```

где `n` -- номер страницы. Что-то вроде этого.